# How to keep divs in a container within another container to display inline and floated right?

Tags: html, css

I want the div "nav" to be floated right and display its divs inline. Also when I resize the browser I want "nav" to slide under "logo" and do so not having divs left on the same line as the logo while other underneath the logo.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="header-container">
    <div id="header-wrap">
        <div class="left logo logoimg">
            <img src="images/Logo-Robert_Fikes_IV.png"/>
        </div>
        <div class="right nav">
            <div class="bluebutton">PORTFOLIO</div>
            <div class="bluebutton">PORTFOLIO</div>
            <div class="bluebutton">PORTFOLIO</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
body {
    background: #000000;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}

#header-container{
    margin: auto;
    padding: 80px 0px 0px;
    max-width: 1160px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}

#header-wrap{
    padding: 0px 40px 0px;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.logo{
    max-width: 440px;
    width: 100%;
}

.logoimg{

}

.nav{
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.bluebutton{
    color: #00bff3;
    border: 1px solid #00bff3;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wse63zzk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done. I changed the nav `divs` to `li` elements, and of course the parent `div` to a `ul`. This is really how you should be making navigation menus for semantic HTML.

Then I just added the following CSS:

```
.nav {
margin-top: 20px;
list-style-type:none;
}
.right.nav li {
float:right;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1y389vb8/)

Comment: Whoa you're a genius! Been messing around with it for so long, I'm a graphic design student and they don't really teach this stuff in schoo, thank you!